# Is every double value rational?

Tags: java

Is every double a rational number (Excluding the special values [Infinity, -Infinity, NaN])? I am leaning towards saying yes, based on the following logic:

- The mantissa has a value that can be represented as a decimal, which can be the numerator.
- The exponent can be converted to a denominator, so that the result is scaled up and down as required.

Is this logic correct, and if not, what is wrong with it, and are there counterexamples which prove double values can be irrational?

Comment: Yes, every double is a rational number.

Comment: Never gave it a real thought but since a `double`, at least as defined in Java, is finite, why wouldn't it be possible to to represent as rational number e.g. `1/3 = 0.33333333 = 33333333/100000000`? Simply because we're talking about a finite number of bits .. you won't have a change to represent anything irrational like π.

Comment: @SamIam what about `Double.NaN`??

Comment: @progyammer `NaN` is literally *not a number* ..

Comment: @progyammer That's not a number

Comment: @SamIam I know. But by _"every double"_, could the person mean _"ever value represented by Double?"_ If NaN is a value represented by Double (well it's not even a value) then _"all Doubles are not rational_", right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logic seems correct.

Computers can use only limited space, meaning they can only represent in memory rational numbers (When using `double` format), as irrational numbers are composed of an infinite number of digits without repeating.

Coming to think about it, you can, however, store an executable code of a function that defines the number, rational or not, but this wouldn't work for every irrational and more importantly, isn't how `double` works.

As for the special values, I don't think so. Infinity is not really a number, so I find it hard to define as rational or irrational. Same for NaN (Which is, by definition, not a number).

Comment: "Computers can use only limited space, meaning they can only represent in memory rational numbers, as irrational numbers are composed of an infinite number of digits" - if you take a base of π instead of 2 for floating point numbers you will be able to represent *some* irrational numbers in limited space. So it's not about the limited space, it is about the format of the double.

Comment: @lexicore This statement assumes the `double` format. The point is that with infinite digits you could represent irrational numbers (in `double` format).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be correct, doubles, at least IEEE 754 with base 2 are rational.

With IEEE 754 you have

```
x = s * m * b^e
```

`s` is sign, `m` is mantissa, `b` is the base 2, `e` is the exponent.

Since `s`, `m`, `b` and `e` are integer, `x` must be rational.